# Mysql database, updating data with a button

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I wanted to make a simple website that whenever you clicked a button the counter on the screen went up. But I also wanted to make it so it saves it to a database so the counter becomes global. I have created a database using PHPMyAdmin and already have a website that uses javascript to make the counter. Is my idea even possible? All the tutorials about MySQL have used the  tags and a different file to connect and save the data to the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible. If you want to save the clicks per day you could make it a table in MySql...

```
CREATE TABLE Clicks (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
clicks INT UNSIGNED,
day TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Or if you just wanted one big entry you could make your table like this...

```
CREATE TABLE Clicks (
clicks INT UNSIGNED
);
```

Either way, your SQL command to update the field will look like...

```
UPDATE Clicks SET clicks = clicks + 1;
/* ^ with out an id (global all clicks ever) ^ */
UPDATE Clicks SET clicks = clicks + 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
/* ^ clicks on the button per day (updating the most recent entry to your table ^ */
```

Then you will just query the SQL table every time your button was clicked.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it you. The website is https://counter.issaquah.xyz if you wanted to see the final result :)